# How to find duplicate lines in many large files?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, performance, large-files, deduplication

I have ~30k files. Each file contains ~100k lines. A line contains no spaces. The lines within an individual file are sorted and duplicate free.

My goal: I want to find all **all** duplicate lines across two or more files and also the names of the files that contained duplicated entries.

A simple solution would be this:

```
cat *.words | sort | uniq -c | grep -v -F '1 '
```

And then I would run:

```
grep 'duplicated entry' *.words
```

Do you see a more efficient way?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since all input files are already sorted, we may bypass the actual sorting step and just use `sort -m` for *merging* the files together.

On some Unix systems (to my knowledge *only* Linux), it may be enough to do

```
sort -m *.words | uniq -d >dupes.txt
```

to get the duplicated lines written to the file `dupes.txt`.

To find what files these lines came from, you may then do

```
grep -Fx -f dupes.txt *.words
```

This will instruct `grep` to treat the lines in `dupes.txt` (`-f dupes.txt`) as *fixed string patterns* (`-F`). `grep` will also require that the whole line matches perfectly from start to finish (`-x`).  It will print the file name and the line to the terminal.

## Non-Linux Unices (or even *more* files)

On some Unix systems, 30000 file names will expand to a string that is too long to pass to a single utility (meaning `sort -m *.words` will fail with `Argument list too long`, which it does on my OpenBSD system). Even Linux will complain about this if the number of files are much larger.

### Finding the dupes

This means that in the general case (this will also work with *many* more than just 30000 files), one has to "chunk" the sorting:

```
rm -f tmpfile
find . -type f -name '*.words' -print0 |
xargs -0 sh -c '
    if [ -f tmpfile ]; then
        sort -o tmpfile -m tmpfile "$@"
    else
        sort -o tmpfile -m "$@"
    fi' sh
```

Alternatively, creating `tmpfile` without `xargs`:

```
rm -f tmpfile
find . -type f -name '*.words' -exec sh -c '
    if [ -f tmpfile ]; then
        sort -o tmpfile -m tmpfile "$@"
    else
        sort -o tmpfile -m "$@"
    fi' sh {} +
```

This will find all files in the current directory (or below) whose names matches `*.words`.  For an appropriately sized chunk of these names at a time, the size of which is determined by `xargs`/`find`, it merges them together into the sorted `tmpfile` file.  If `tmpfile` already exists (for all but the first chunk), this file is also merged with the other files in the current chunk. Depending on the length of your filenames, and the maximum allowed length of a command line, this may require more or much more than 10 individual runs of the internal script (`find`/`xargs` will do this automatically).

The "internal" `sh` script,

```
if [ -f tmpfile ]; then
    sort -o tmpfile -m tmpfile "$@"
else
    sort -o tmpfile -m "$@"
fi
```

uses `sort -o tmpfile` to output to `tmpfile` (this won't overwrite `tmpfile` even if this is also an input to `sort`) and `-m` for doing the merge. In both branches, `"$@"` will expand to a list of individually quoted filenames passed to the script from `find` or `xargs`.

Then, just run `uniq -d` on `tmpfile` to get all line that are duplicated:

```
uniq -d tmpfile >dupes.txt
```

---

If you like the "DRY" principle ("Don't Repeat Yourself"), you may write the internal script as

```
if [ -f tmpfile ]; then
    t=tmpfile
else
    t=/dev/null
fi

sort -o tmpfile -m "$t" "$@"
```

or

```
t=tmpfile
[ ! -f "$t" ] && t=/dev/null
sort -o tmpfile -m "$t" "$@"
```

---

### Where did they come from?

For the same reasons as above, we can't use `grep -Fx -f dupes.txt *.words` to find where these duplications came from, so instead we use `find` again:

```
find . -type f -name '*.words' \
    -exec grep -Fx -f dupes.txt {} +
```

Since there is no "complicated" processing to be done, we may invoke `grep` directly from `-exec`.  The `-exec` option takes a utility command and will place the found names in `{}`.  With `+` at the end, `find` will place as many arguments in place of `{}` as the current shell supports in each invocation of the utility.

To be *totally* correct, one may want to use either

```
find . -type f -name '*.words' \
    -exec grep -H -Fx -f dupes.txt {} +
```

or

```
find . -type f -name '*.words' \
    -exec grep -Fx -f dupes.txt /dev/null {} +
```

to be sure that filenames are always included in the output from `grep`.

The first variation uses `grep -H` to always output matching filenames. The last variation uses the fact that `grep` will include the name of the matching file if *more than one file* is given on the command line.

This matters since the last chunk of filenames sent to `grep` from `find` may actually only contain a single filename, in which case `grep` would not mention it in its results.

---

Bonus material:

### Dissecting the `find`+`xargs`+`sh` command:

```
find . -type f -name '*.words' -print0 |
xargs -0 sh -c '
    if [ -f tmpfile ]; then
        sort -o tmpfile -m tmpfile "$@"
    else
        sort -o tmpfile -m "$@"
    fi' sh
```

`find . -type f -name '*.words'` will simply generate a list of pathnames from the current directory (or below) where each pathnames is that of a *regular file* (`-type f`) and that has a filename component at the end that matches `*.words`.  If only the *current* directory is to be searched, one may add `-maxdepth 1` after the `.`, before `-type f`.

`-print0` will ensure that all found pathnames are outputted with a `\0` (`nul`) character as delimiter.  This is a character that is not valid in a Unix path and it enables us to process pathnames even if they contain newline characters (or other weird things).

`find` pipes its output to `xargs`.

`xargs -0` will read the `\0`-delimited list of pathnames and will execute the given utility repeatedly with chunks of these, ensuring that the utility is executed with just enough arguments to not cause the shell to complain about a too long argument list, until there is no more input from `find`.

The utility invoked by `xargs` is `sh` with a script given on the command line as a string using its `-c` flag.

When invoking `sh -c '...some script...'` with arguments following, the arguments will be available to the script in `$@`, *except for the first argument*, which will be placed in `$0` (this is the "command name" that you may spot in e.g. `top` if you are quick enough).  This is why we insert the string `sh` as the first argument after the end of the actual script.  The string `sh` is a *dummy argument* and could be any single word (some seem to prefer `_` or `sh-find`).

Comment: At the end of your 1st block of shell script, what is the use of `fi' sh`?

Comment: @danielAzuelos The `fi` is the end of the `if` statement in the "internal" `sh` shell script.  The `'` ends that shell script  (the whole script is a singly quoted string).  The `sh` will be passed to the internal script in `$0` (not part of `$@`, which will contain the filenames).  In this instance, that `sh` string may actually be _any_ word. If leaving out `sh` at the end, the first filename would be passed in `$0` and would not be part of the processing that the internal shell script is doing.

Comment: To clarify, the script solutions for more than 30K files works by concatenating and sorting every single file in the directory tree into one large file, which can then be checked for duplicates?

Comment: @Prometheus Yes, more or less. Note that the question here states that each file already is sorted, so we don't need to sort the individual files, only merge them into the larger corpus.

Answer (score 8):

> The lines within an individual file are sorted and duplicate free.

Which means you probably might find some use for `sort -m`:

```
 -m, --merge
        merge already sorted files; do not sort
```

The other obvious alternative to doing this would be a simple `awk` to collect the lines in an array, and count them. But as [@dave_thompson_085](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/423478/how-to-find-duplicate-lines-in-many-large-files/423483?noredirect=1#comment762728_423485) commented, those 3 000 million lines (or however many unique ones there are) would likely take some considerable amount of memory to store, so that may not work very well.

Answer (score 4):

With awk you can get all repeated lines in all files in one short command:

```
$ awk '_[$0]++' *.words
```

But it will repeat lines if a line exist 3 or more times.
There is a solution to get only the first duplicate:

```
$ awk '_[$0]++==1' *.words
```

It should be pretty quick (if repeats are few) but will eat a lot of memory to keep all lines in memory. Maybe, depending on your actual files and repeats, try with 3 or four files first.

```
$ awk '_[$0]++==1' [123]*.words
```

Otherwise, you can do:

```
$ sort -m *.words | uniq -d
```

Which will print uniq repeated lines.

Comment: +1 for `sort -m * | uniq -d`

Comment: awk can avoid the repeats with `'x[$0]++==1'` but will indeed need a lot of memory; if the 3G lines have say 1G distinct values, and if your awk needs say 50 bytes for a hasharray entry mapping a (presumably shortish) string to the uninit value, that's 50GB. For sorted input, you can do `uniq -d` manually with `awk '$0==p&&n++==1;$0!=p{p=$0;n=1}'` but why bother?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for the concept of `==1`, great idea.

Comment: Assuming 30000 files with 100000 lines of 80 characters each and _no duplicates_, this will require `awk` to store 2.4E11 bytes (223 GiB).

Comment: `sort -m *.words | uniq -d` works great!

After the process I run `grep` to find a files that contain a duplicated entry. Do you see a way to print the at least one filename that contains a duplicated entry?

Comment: @LarsSchneider, that sounds like a [new Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)...

Answer (score 3):

Optimized **`sort`** + **`uniq`** solution:

```
sort --parallel=30000 *.words | uniq -d
```

- `--parallel=N` - change the number of sorts run concurrently to `N`
- `-d, --repeated` - only print duplicate lines, one for each group

Comment: I'm curious as to whether this would be faster than the script solutions in Kusalananda's answer.

Answer (score 0):

`comm` is another tool for these kinds of tasks, only caveat is that it requires presorted data sources. `<(...)` syntax is available in most modern shells.

```
# suppress common lines
comm -3 <(echo "1\n2") <(echo "3\n1"| sort)
2
       3


# display common lines
comm -12 <(echo "1\n2") <(echo "1\n3") 
1
```